# Open urls from a mark_text() data table that was filtered based on chart selections

Tags: python, visualization, altair, vega-lite

I'm trying to display a table of url values based on interactive selections.

I am able to display it, following the example on the docs, but I want to be able to click on one of the urls in the table and have it open it in a new tab.

Idea is to have multiple charts and their selections filter down the url data table.

This way the user can choose one of the rows from the table and open up the source link of that row, or in this case a google search.

From what I gathered, I should be using href='url' as one of the encodings, but it has no effect.

Here's the code I've been testing it on:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
from urllib.parse import urlencode

source = data.cars()

# placeholder url column
def make_google_query(name):
    return "https://www.google.com/search?" + urlencode({'q': '"{0}"'.format(name)})

source['url'] = source['Name'].apply(make_google_query)

# Brush for selection
brush = alt.selection_interval()

# Scatter Plot
points = alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower:Q',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
    color=alt.condition(brush, alt.value('steelblue'), alt.value('grey'))
).add_params(brush)

# Base chart for data tables
ranked_text = alt.Chart(source).mark_text(align='right').encode(
    y=alt.Y('row_number:O').axis(None)
).transform_filter(
    brush
).transform_window(
    row_number='row_number()'
).transform_filter(
    alt.datum.row_number < 15
)

# Data Table
urls = ranked_text.encode(text='url:N').properties(
    title=alt.Title(text='url', align='right')
)

# Build chart
alt.hconcat(
    points,
    urls
).resolve_legend(
    color="independent"
).configure_view(
    stroke=None
)
```

Comment: I'm unsure why it doesn't work with mark text. If you use it with mark_circle like in this example it should work https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/scatter_href.html. Maybe create a smaller example and post as a bug on the vega-lite issue tracker if it reproduces?